# Linq-to-SQL DataContext update

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am getting this runtime exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal' to
>   type 'System.String'.

How can I fix my code to get my result without exceptions?

```
ProductsDataContext db = new ProductsDataContext(); 

var matchedproduct = db.GetTable<product>().SingleOrDefault(p =>p.ProductID==productID);

if (matchedproduct != null)               
   product.ProductName = txtpname.Text;

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't getting a compile time error its because your dbml doesn't accurately depict the column in your database.  Your object thinks its a string but its clearly a decimal in the database.  You should update it in the dbml editor.  Then when you set product name you will have to parse out the decimal value from the Text.